# Notification not received for some Gmail watched accounts

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

We use Google Pub/Sub service for being notified when our users receive emails on their Gmail accounts.

We use the Ruby Gmail client (https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/Google/Apis/GmailV1/GmailService.html) for watching the Gmail accounts of our user (connected with OAuth authorisation). We expose an endpoint in our Rails app for getting the posted notifications from Google.

It has worked for years without any problem for more than 1000 Gmail accounts. Since two weeks ago, we stopped receiving notifications for some accounts (I would say around 20).
Each account is re-watched once a day (with stop_user() and then watch_user()), so it's not a problem of expired subscription.

Once a notification is not received for an account when there is a new mail, we never receive a notification anymore until it's re-watched. Then, it works for several minutes/hours and then it's broken again. It always happens for the same accounts.

The quotas page on GCP shows that there is not quotas limit exceeded.

I don't know if it's directly related to the Pub/Sub service or if it's a Gmail issue...

Does someone already experienced the same issue ? How can it be investigated / fixed ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Rémi

Comment: This sounds like a bug maybe check the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191602%2B)

Comment: As @DaImTo says, it seems like a bug. Also you can check in the [Pub/Sub](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentId:187173%2B) component.

Comment: Thank you. I created an issue since I didn't found existing similar issue : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/206873634

Answer (score 0):

As talked in the comments, this seems to be a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/206873634). Adding it as an answer for visibility purposes. You can click on the star next to the issue number to give more priority to the report and to receive updates.

Answer (score 0):

A bug has been created here on the Google issue tracker : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/208369302

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).